# indice indefinido en PHP

Tags: php, html, pdo, post

> Tengo un problema me dice indice indefinido y no se por que me dice indice indefinido en $_POST['email'] y $_POST['email'] no se si por que no se esta conectando estoy utilizando PDO para la conexion.

### HTML

```
    <form method="post" action="Registro.php">
        <input  name="email" placeholder="Correo">
        </br>
        <input name="pass" placeholder="Contraseña">
        </br>
        <div class="posicion">
        <a href="" id="Guardar" type="submit" class="btn btn-color">Guardar</a>
    </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

---

### php

```
 $email = $_POST['email'];
 $pass = $_POST['pass'];

   if(isset($_POST['guardar'])){
       $Con = $con->query( "SELECT * FROM usuarios VALUES email= '$email'");
         if($Con -> rowCount()>0){
          $mensaje ="<script>
          Swal.fire({
          icon: 'error',
          title: 'Oops...',
          text: 'Correoya registrado',
          footer: '<a href>Why do I have this issue?</a>'
      })
      </script>";
    }
```

Comment: ¿Seguro que estas mandando al archivo correcto esos datos?

Comment: Reemplaza todo el código PHP por un `var_dump($_POST)` y comprueba si recibe toda la información del formulario. Adicionalmente, comprueba si se muestra el `var_dump` solo cuando envías el formulario o incluso cuando accedes al formulario o nunca (que también es posible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este es el problema
Tu codigo empieza asi:

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];
```

Y deberia ser asi:

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
$email = $_POST['email'];
$pass = $_POST['pass']; 
}
```

Dentro de esas llaves escribir todo lo demas
Podrias tambien llamar tu archivo PHP primero y luego con un require la vista en tu caso el formulario y asi eliminar el action

Comment: Creo amigo que es mejor agregarlo, podria estar trabajando con dos metodos y encerrar cada uno en su respectivo espacio, es necesario

Comment: Los saquepara saber donde estaba el error ($email = $_POST['email'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];) mi codigo como lo tenia era este : if(isset($_POST['Guardar'])){
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $pass = $_POST['pass'];

Comment: otra duda como se que se esta mandando ya que lo puse lo que comentaste y no me aguarda los datos o no se si se envian.

Comment: haz un var_dump de cada uno

Answer (score 0):

1. Primero de todo comprueba si estás enviando el formulario a la ruta correcta (mayúsculas, minúsculas, etc).
2. Después, reemplaza todo el código de `Registro.php` por un `var_dump($_POST);` y comprueba si se muestran los datos enviados.
3. Si llegan todos los datos, es posible que estés obteniendo el valor de `$_POST['email`] y el de `$_POST['pass']` en todas las solicitudes (incluidas las que no han enviado el formulario):

Una de las muchas soluciones que hay es simplemente **indicar a PHP una alternativa** en el caso de no encontrar la información:

```
$email = $_POST['email'] ?? null;
$pass = $_POST['pass'] ?? null;
```

Con esta solución estarás introduciendo un valor nulo en `$email` y `$pass` en caso de que no se encuentren los datos.

Otra solución es ejecutar el código relacionado con el envío del formulario **solo cuando este es enviado**:

```
if (isset($_POST['guardar'])) {
    // Todo el código relacionado con el formulario (Obtener datos, envío, etc...)
}
```

Para usar esta última solución, ten en cuenta que **necesitarás agregar al formulario un botón** ya sea mediante `<input type="button" name="guardar" />` o mediante `<button type="submit" name="guardar">Guardar</button>` **con el atributo** `name="guardar"` para que se pueda realizar la comprobación de envío del formulario.

Comment: mi codigo original era : if(isset($_POST['Guardar'])){
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $pass = $_POST['pass'];      pero no me mandaba ningun error debido a que la condicion no se ejecutaba asi que tuve que sacarlos para saber si era el error al recibir los datos

Comment: ¿Has probado todas las soluciones? Lo que pasa es que no tienes ningún botón con `name="guardar"`, de modo que es imposible que se ejecute el código. Lee la solución 3 hasta el final.